# how to use a function to call other functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Excuse me, i am a beginner to learn python.
I want to create a function to call other functions by python.

this is my logic:

```
def1(parameters1):
    variable1 
    return variable1
def2(parameters2):
    variable2 
    return variable2
def3(parameters3):
    variable3 
    return variable3
```

finally `def4` can call `def1`,`def2`,`def3`

How to do it?  What articles I can read them?

Comment: Just call them in def4, it works

Comment: [Calling other functions tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-call-function-from-another-function/)

Comment: You call a function in a function the same way you call a function anywhere else. What, **exactly** is the problem? Please actual code, the above is ambiguous, it doesn't have to be.

Comment: The syntax you're using in your post is wrong... perhaps you were just substituting, but in any case I would just suggest taking a beginner's Python tutorial to try to answer your question, since knowing how to define and call functions is a basic question about the language. Try tutorialspoint, really anything works at the very beginning level. In the future keep in mind that you should ask a question on StackOverflow only after you've tried to find the answer yourself, with at least a google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to define your functions slightly differently. They should look like the following:

```py
def func1(parameters1):
    variable1 
    return variable1

def func2(parameters2):
    variable2 
    return variable2

def func3(parameters3):
    variable3 
    return variable3
```

You can then call those functions like this:

```py
def func4(input):
    variable_1 = func1(input)
    variable_2 = func2(variable_1)
    variable_3 = func3(variable_2)
    return variable_3
```